# Is there a way of implementing a list into a button function while using html script?

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I am trying to integrate a list that I have written in html/css into the java string for displaying a button.

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click here for a 
    list of other Engineering majors!</button>
```

I cannot figure out how to display my list,

```
<ul class="majorlist">
    <li> Computer Engineer </li>
    <li> Computer Science </li>
    <li> Electrical Engineering </li>
    <li> Mechanical Engineering </li>
    <li> Chemical Engineering </li>
    <li> Bio Engineering </li>
</ul>
```

through the user clicking the button. Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't know much javascript, you can just use jquery, it's super easy with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is.It uses jQuery.:

```
function myFunction()
{
      $('body').append('<ul class="majorlist"><li> Computer Engineer </li><li> Computer Science </li><li> Electrical Engineering </li><li> Mechanical Engineering </li><li> Chemical Engineering </li><li> Bio Engineering </li></ul>');
}
```

More Info [here](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to change whether the list is visible. The normal CSS for the `majorlist` class would hide it, then the button can add a `visible` class that makes it visible.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('majorlist')[0].className += " visible";
}
```

```css
.majorlist {
  display: none;
}
.majorlist.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click here for a list of other Engineering majors!</button>

<ul class="majorlist">
  <li>Computer Engineer</li>
  <li>Computer Science</li>
  <li>Electrical Engineering</li>
  <li>Mechanical Engineering</li>
  <li>Chemical Engineering</li>
  <li>Bio Engineering</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS, make the list non-visible by default:

```
.majorlist
{
    display: none;
}
```

Then in your `onclick` handler, change that style:

```
function myFunction()
{
    var list = document.querySelector(".majorlist");
    list.style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript

```js
    function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("mylist").style.display = '';
    }
```

```html
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click here for a 
        list of other Engineering majors!</button>
    <ul class="majorlist" id="mylist" style="display:none;">
        <li> Computer Engineer </li>
        <li> Computer Science </li>
        <li> Electrical Engineering </li>
        <li> Mechanical Engineering </li>
        <li> Chemical Engineering </li>
        <li> Bio Engineering </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as that, pure JS (function for toggle is there too):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showList() {
    document.getElementById('list').style.display = "block";
}
function toggleList() {
    var list = document.getElementById('list');
    list.style.display = list.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'; 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="showList();">Click here for a 
    list of other Engineering majors!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="toggleList();">Click here to toggle a 
    list of other Engineering majors!</button>
<ul id="list" style="display:none;">
    <li> Computer Engineer </li>
    <li> Computer Science </li>
    <li> Electrical Engineering </li>
    <li> Mechanical Engineering </li>
    <li> Chemical Engineering </li>
    <li> Bio Engineering </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Check this code [online](http://jsfiddle.net/6beqt8rL/).